# Replace spaces and remove non-word characters in single preg_replace() call

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this code which does what I want, but in four steps. I want only alphanumeric lower case letters, and space should be replaced by an underscore. I have written this function but want to learn if it's possible with one `preg_replace()` function call:

```
      $str = 'qwerty!@#$@#$^@#$Hello %#$sdsdsss';
      $cityu= strtolower($str);
     $id = str_replace(' ', '_', $cityu);
      $outcome = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", "", $id);

       var_dump($outcome);
```

I want one `preg_replace()` to do this.

Comment: i dont understand the meaning of negative vote i asked something which was already solved by me but i wanted a better way for efficient solution but public are giving negative vote bad very bad

Comment: @chriz  what is the meaning of this much negative vote i have not done any crime asked an  good question

Comment: To be clear, you only want to keep alphanumeric characters and underscores (i.e., "word" characters). You also want to replace the spaces with underscores. Before reading the code, I interpreted your question, which read "alpha numeric lower case letters and space to be replaced by an underscore", as yielding something like `_!@#$@#$^@#$_%#$_`.

Comment: Who said anything about me voting?!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I can only wager a guess. Perhaps it's seen as "not useful" in general, as it only applies specifically to your scenario and may not really help anyone else. Otherwise, I don't feel it's a poorly worded or stupid question.

Comment: @Wiseguy i aplogize for that sorry

Comment: I think some voted it down because they saw others voted it down...

Comment: Some people getting obsessed with down votes. I am voting you up.

Comment: @itachi thx my question may be specific but if you will see and think its general problem most users face

Comment: Following on from your most recent question, and your comments about why a question was downvoted. In this case again, the question was written in lower case and without punctuation (see the [edits here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15575012/revisions)). This does make it a bit more difficult to read, and busy readers here have high expectations about prior effort! It doesn't need to be poetry, but make it as readable as you can - it might save you a few downvotes `:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a single replacement string since you're doing two distinct operations, but [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) can take arrays as arguments. This allows you to makes multiple sets of replacements in a single `preg_replace()` call.

```
$str = strtolower('qwerty!@#$@#$^@#$Hello %#$sdsdsss');
echo preg_replace(array('/ /', '/\W/'), array('_', ''), $str);

// output:  qwertyhello_sdsdsss
```

`\W` is a negated shorthand [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which is equivalent to `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`.

---

Note that replacement order matters. Replacements will occur in the order they're listed, so you would get a different result in reverse order: first non-word characters would be replaced, then spaces, but the spaces will already have been removed in the first step.

```
echo preg_replace(array('/\W/', '/ /'), array('', '_'), $str);

// output:  qwertyhellosdsdsss
```